# How to add class on scroll in ionic2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I want to add animation in my Ionic2 app on scrolling, but I can't add classes on scroll so the animation didn't happen on scrolling, all animations are fired at one time.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is an `ionScroll` event emitter available on `ion-content` so you can subscribe to it and do whatever you need. You can find more in [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#output-events).

Here is an example:

template.html

```
<ion-content #content></ion-content>
```

component.js

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'

@Component({...})
export class Component {
  @ViewChild('content') content = null

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.content.ionScroll.subscribe(event => {
      // do what you need here
      console.log(event)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir thank you for reply, but i want animation in every section like this [link](http://codepen.io/syedrafeeq/full/yEJKn/) .